# Invariant Violation: Text strings must be rendered within a component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

i am trying to print the numbers from 1 to 10 such that a user can press on any of these.
However ,I am getting this error which reads

> Invariant Violation: Text strings must be rendered within a `<Text>`
>   component.

Here is the code inside render .

```
render(){
         let arr=[];
         for(let index=1;index<=this.state.max_rating;index++){
             arr.push(
                 <TouchableOpacity
                      activeOpacity={0.7}
                      key={index}
                      onPress={this.UpdateRating.bind(this, index)}>
                      <Text key={index}>
                        {'lol'}
                      </Text>
                   >
                </TouchableOpacity>
              );
         }

         return(
             <View style={styles.MainContainer}>
              <Text> The code is working man </Text>
              <View style={styles.childView}>{arr}</View>
             </View>
         );
     }
```

Comment: there's an extra > in your code , see this https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-wc6hfq  it's working properly

Answer (score 3):

There is a slight syntax issue in your code

```
for(let index=1;index<=this.state.max_rating;index++){
         arr.push(
             <TouchableOpacity
                  activeOpacity={0.7}
                  key={index}
                  onPress={this.UpdateRating.bind(this, index)}>
                  <Text key={index}>
                    {'lol'}
                  </Text>
               > <-- extra character which is treated as a string giving you the warning
            </TouchableOpacity>
          );
     }
```

Remove the `>` character rendered within `<TouchableOpacity>` component and it will work fine